# Video Player plugin for Flutter not working correctly when deploy to Firebase hosting

Tags: flutter, firebase-hosting, flutter-video-player

I have built the widget that uses `video_player 2.6.0` package from [https://pub.dev/packages/video_player](https://stackoverflow.com).

This is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

void main() => runApp(const VideoApp());

/// Stateful widget to fetch and then display video content.
class VideoApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoApp({super.key});

  @override
  _VideoAppState createState() => _VideoAppState();
}

class _VideoAppState extends State<VideoApp> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4')
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Video Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: _controller.value.isInitialized
              ? AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                  child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                )
              : Container(),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _controller.value.isPlaying
                  ? _controller.pause()
                  : _controller.play();
            });
          },
          child: Icon(
            _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller. Dispose();
  }
}
```

I can play the video when debug on Chrome, but when I deploy to Firebase hosting follow by this instruction [https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting](https://stackoverflow.com), that video can not play.

Could you please help me on this issue?
Thanks.

Do the same code from example section of the `video_player 2.6.0` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: `For Web, not all video formats are supported`

The Web platform does not suppport dart:io, so avoid using the VideoPlayerController.file constructor for the plugin. Using the constructor attempts to create a VideoPlayerController.file that will throw an UnimplementedError.

- Different web browsers may have different video-playback capabilities (supported formats, autoplay...).
- The VideoPlayerOptions.mixWithOthers option can't be implemented in web, at least at the moment. If you use this option in web it will be silently ignored.

> Supported Formats

On Web, available formats depend on your users' browsers (vendor and version).

> Limitations on the Web platform

Video playback on the Web platform has some limitations that might surprise developers more familiar with mobile/desktop targets.

In no particular order:

> dart:io

The web platform does not suppport dart:io, so attempts to create a VideoPlayerController.file will throw an UnimplementedError.

> Autoplay

Attempts to start playing videos with an audio track (or not muted) without user interaction with the site ("user activation") will be prohibited by the browser and cause runtime errors in JS.

Check package:[video_player_web](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player_web) for more web-specific information.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Yes, I have read that instruction but there is no instruction for what format of video can play on browser. Could you please explain more specifically the answer?

Comment: Assuming you have cross-checked your implementation as per the instructions, I would suggest go for most common video format .mp4. Try step debugging using print, debugPrint or log whichever you find useful in production. 

Also check with the different build methods:

flutter build web --web-renderer html or, 
flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit

Comment: I have add --web-renderer html to the build web command and that solved the issue. Thank you.